# current-user_can not working in loop

Tags: loop, user-roles

I am using the following loop to show the-content for only contributors as well as Google visitors.  But somehow it is not working.

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<?php if (current_user_can(‘contributor’) || strpos($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER], "google") == true) { ?>
<?php the_content('');?><?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

From Codex :

> Do not pass a role name to current_user_can(), as this is not
>   guaranteed to work correctly (see #[22624](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624)) Instead, you may wish to try the [check user role function](http://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/wordpress-check-user-role-function/) put together by AppThemes.

I would propose to use `is_user_logged_in()` to check your function.

Comment: If this answer your question, please check it as answered please.